# How to stop AVPlayer playback in cell when the cell has moved offscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avplayer

**Scenario**: I have a `tableView` with many cells. Each cell will contain an AVPlayer to play a video. The AVPlayer is being created once the user presses a play button on the cell. I want the AVPlayer to stop playing it's video and be **completely** removed upon it's cell moving offscreen.

**The Issue**: When the cell moves offscreen the media will still play. So when I attempt to remove the player like I need, my app crashes with an error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of AVPlayer cannot remove a time observer that was added by a different instance of AVPlayer.'

---

**How the player is being created**:

(in the cell)

```
-(void)addPlayer {

    if (!self.player) {

        // This is my custom init method
        self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithFrame:self.container.bounds contentURL:mediaURL];
        [self.player setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.container setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.container addSubview:self.player];
    }

}
```

---

**How the addTimeObserver is being added**:

```
-(void)beginObservingTime {

// This will monitor the current time of the player

    __weak STPlayer *weakSelf = self;
    self.observerToken = [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, NSEC_PER_SEC) queue:nil usingBlock:^ (CMTime time) {
        if (CMTimeGetSeconds(time) > self.playbackTime) {
            // done buffering
            [weakSelf updatePlaybackTime:CMTimeGetSeconds(time)];
            [weakSelf.player removeTimeObserver:weakSelf.observerToken];
            [weakSelf hideActivityIndicator];
        }
    }];
}
```

---

**How the player is being removed**:

(in the UITableViewController)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(FeedCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [cell breakDownPlayer];
}
```

(in the cell)

```
-(void)breakDownPlayer {

    [self.player breakDown];
}
```

(in player subclass)

```
-(void)breakDown {

    [self.player removeTimeObserver:self.observerToken];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:self.playerItem];
}
```

**Question**: How do I remove the player from a `UITableViewCell` once `didEndDisplayingCell` has been called and the app not crash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting the player to nil in the didEndDisplayingCell method?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(FeedCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (cell.player.rate != 0 && (cell.player.error == nil)) {
    // player is playing
    cell.playButton.hidden = NO;
    cell.player = nil;
  }  
}
```

Comment: I should have known... Thanks.